# What is the most efficient method to grind kills on Cubemen?

Tags: achievements, cubemen

> **WARRIOR LEGEND**
>
> Kill 50,000 Enemy Cubemen

With all levels and other achievements done, I am still 15k Kills short to complete the last achievement, Warrior Legend.

**What is the most efficient way to grind this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endless mode on level Cube.

During the latter waves, the only enemies are Deadly Rain which attack from above. Because of the top floor in the level Cube, the Deadly Rain cannot easily kill your forces on the bottom floor. The Deadly Rain begin moving in large groups over time as you last more waves so your survivability is tied to your efficiency. Use plenty of AOE.

Stack the side near the enemy spawn mostly with Fred to slow the enemy to a standstill and then cover the remainder of the bottom floor with Flint. Stack the top level with Ricky where they can target the enemy spawn and Sid in the far corner where the Ricky can't aim from. the other spots can't target the creep spawn so don't worry about them.

```
Bottom Floor    Top Floor

FlFlFlFlFlFl    MiRiRiRiSiSi
Fl        Fl    Mi        Si
Fl        Fl    Mi        Ri
Fr        Fl    ||        Ri
Fr    ____Mo    ||____    Ri
Fr[]Fr_____|    |_____  []_|
```

Monitor the game until the only enemies spawning are Deadly Rain (around wave 90~100), making sure to replenish and heal your forces as needed. Check in every 10-20 minutes to throw down a Mike if needed, but your units will really only be taking hits because of a fluke so the rest is auto-pilot. Leave the game running for an extended period and when you are done you will have thousands of kills. Be sure to go into the options and turn off the setting to pause when the game loses focus because this will take several hours.

While I can't conclusively prove that this is the "most efficient", the spawn rates do not really improve drastically so a setup like this is probably pretty close. Because your kill rates drop as the enemies get stronger, your most efficient path is to end it around wave 500 (just under 4000 kills) or maybe even sooner and then go again for at most another dozen runs to get the achievement. Eventually you will stop getting kills at all and will be forced to end it some time around 5000 kills. For high score, feel free to leave it as this setup is unstoppable with the enemies literally frozen in place and unable to hurt your units. Simply set it up and let it do its thing until you get to wave 500-700 or so.

Comment: This is boss, +1